# Prices of large vacuum chamber

Tags: vacuum

This may seem like an odd question for Physics, but I'm pretty sure this exact answer was given in this forum about six months ago, but I can no longer find the thread.

A rule of thumb was posted for pricing out large vacuum systems based on total volume. The context was the construction of small particle accelerator systems like one you might find at a university.

Comment: Recently we were quoted 3x the price and 2x the delivery time for a custom vacuum chamber relative to what we had expected about a year ago. Apparently the semiconductor industry is ordering lots of stuff, so the main suppliers are slammed. Your mileage may vary...

Comment: @JonCuster - do you mind me asking what the original quote was, measured in terms of a per-volume number? I don't need the actual dollar figure, just some sense of the scaling.

Comment: Well, it is a particularly complex chamber, with a sliding section for access to the center of the chamber. Capable of 1E-9 Torr. Very roughly 4m long, 1m diameter, original estimate was ~$600k. Most of your stuff is likely covered by off-the-shelf pipes and crosses, now? Except for the acceleration column and magnet chamber? You might see what National Electrostatic is quoting these days for some of their standard items.

Comment: Are you remembering [Low cost Ultra High Vaccum Chamber and Atomic Force Microscope](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/628608/low-cost-ultra-high-vaccum-chamber-and-atomic-force-microscope)?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because shopping advice is generally off-topic.

Comment: @JohnRennie - no, but that is useful as well. I definitely remember it being stated in the context of a scaling, something like "well we always use X per Y volume as a rule of thumb".

Comment: @Qmechanic - this has nothing to do with shopping. I am not building anything, Not sure why you think this is shopping related?